# Why does SQL plus is not showing the result on terminal even when it is executing on db successful?

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

I have written a bash script which connects to the db and run query. These query are fetched from a file. This was working till I was using mysql on local desktop using lampp. But now connecting db on other server using sqlplus64 is returning

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

    -H         Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
           usage help.
    -V         Displays the SQL*Plus version.

Usage 2: sqlplus [ [<option>] [{logon | /nolog}] [<start>] ]

  <option> is: [-AC] [-C <version>] [-L] [-M "<options>"] [-NOLOGINTIME] [-R <level>]
           [-S]

    -AC        Enable Application Continuity.
    -C <version>   Sets the compatibility of affected commands to the
           version specified by <version>.  The version has
           the form "x.y[.z]".  For example, -C 10.2.0
    -L         Attempts to log on just once, instead of
           reprompting on error.
    -M "<options>" Sets automatic HTML or CSV markup of output.  The options
           have the form:
           {HTML html_options|CSV csv_options}
           See SQL*Plus User's Guide for detailed HTML and CSV options.
    -NOLOGINTIME   Don't display Last Successful Login Time.
    -R <level>     Sets restricted mode to disable SQL*Plus commands
           that interact with the file system.  The level can
           be 1, 2 or 3.  The most restrictive is -R 3 which
           disables all user commands interacting with the
           file system.
    -S         Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
           the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
           commands.

  <logon> is: {<username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | / }
          [AS {SYSDBA | SYSOPER | SYSASM | SYSBACKUP | SYSDG | SYSKM | SYSRAC}] [EDITION=value]

    Specifies the database account username, password and connect
    identifier for the database connection.  Without a connect
    identifier, SQL*Plus connects to the default database.

    The AS SYSDBA, AS SYSOPER, AS SYSASM, AS SYSBACKUP, AS SYSDG,
    AS SYSKM and AS SYSRAC options are database administration privileges.

    <connect_identifier> can be in the form of Net Service Name
    or Easy Connect.

      @[<net_service_name> | [//]Host[:Port]/<service_name>]

    <net_service_name> is a simple name for a service that resolves
    to a connect descriptor.

    Example: Connect to database using Net Service Name and the
         database net service name is ORCL.

       sqlplus myusername/mypassword@ORCL

    Host specifies the host name or IP address of the database
    server computer.

    Port specifies the listening port on the database server.

    <service_name> specifies the service name of the database you
    want to access.

    Example: Connect to database using Easy Connect and the
         Service name is ORCL.

       sqlplus myusername/mypassword@Host/ORCL

    The /NOLOG option starts SQL*Plus without connecting to a
    database.

    The EDITION specifies the value for Session Edition.


  <start> is: @<URL>|<filename>[.<ext>] [<parameter> ...]

    Runs the specified SQL*Plus script from a web server (URL) or the
    local file system (filename.ext) with specified parameters that
    will be assigned to substitution variables in the script.

When SQL*Plus starts, and after CONNECT commands, the site profile
(e.g. $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql) and the user profile
(e.g. login.sql in the working directory) are run.  The files may
contain SQL*Plus commands.

Refer to the SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference for more information.
this query is duplicate and is not executed
```

Why am I not able to see the successful output and the error code ?

This is my bash script

```
RAW=`cat sqlTemp.sql`
IFS=";"
for var in $RAW
query=$(echo $var | sed  '/^$/d')
do
sqlplus64 username/password@hostname:portnumber/servicename $query 2>>errorLog.txt

done
```

content of my sqlTemp.sql

```
select name from TEMP_DB_QUERY_AUTOMATIO;
select *from TEMP_DB_QUERY_AUTOMATION;
select *from TEMP_DB_QUERY_AUTOMATION;
select qlid from TEMP_DB_QUERY_AUTOMATION;
select *from TEMP_DB_QUERY_AUTOMATION;
select email TEMP_DB_QUERY_AUTOMATION;
```

Comment: What is the content of your `sqlTemp.sql` file?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i am adding the content in the question .

Comment: Is it encoded as UTF-8 with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i dont know about UTF-8 .

Comment: Then check settings of your editor.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit no error in format.this is working                            `sqlplus64 -S username/password@hostname:portnumber/servicename <<ENDOFSQL
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
$querry
exit;
ENDOFSQLE` .